# ASP.Net Repeater Responsive Controls Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, responsive-design, asprepeater

I have ASP.Net controls for search attributes with check box options and ASP.NET repeater. For Responsive Design, I have same bindings in two different places to match the design.

Here, CheckBoxList  ID=Options1 & ID=Options2 both having same binding but the code will repeat. I have 400 lines to check the conditions for single binding. i have to duplicate all the codes again for the another view.  **Is there any way to optimize the code to single bind with both views handling. ( Avoid duplicate binding and checking)?**

```
// Desktop View

<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs narrowSearch">
//Content
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAttributes1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="rptAttributes_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<div class="form">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Options1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Visible="false"
DataTextField="EnOptionName" DataValueField="SubCategoryAttributeOptionID" Font-Strikeout="False" />
</div>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>

// Mobile view

 <div class="sec_left  hidden-lg hidden-md"> 
 <div class="moremenu narrowSearch">
//Content
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptAttribute2" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="rptAttributes_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<div class="form">
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Options2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Visible="false"
DataTextField="EnOptionName" DataValueField="SubCategoryAttributeOptionID" Font-Strikeout="False" />
</div>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
 CheckBoxList chklOptions1 = item.FindControl("Options1") as CheckBoxList;
 CheckBoxList chklOptions2 = item.FindControl("Options2") as CheckBoxList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place your repeater (including the declarative code as well as what you have in the code-behind of your page) into a custom user control. Then you put the user control in each section (desktop and mobile) of your page. This is the simplest way to avoid repeated code. Having said this, since you've only provided part of the code that's in the code-behind class of your page, I can't speak to what changes might be required when you move the imperative code you have in your page's code-behind class to the user control.

Good luck!

Comment: For Example, I have to check the checkbox property value currently I use this code.  

if (options.Checked == true)
        {
            _lstProducts = _lstProducts.Intersect(lstDeals).ToList();
        }

but in this case I have to repeat check for both view



if (options1.Checked == true)
        {
            _lstProducts = _lstProducts.Intersect(lstDeals).ToList();
        }

if (options2.Checked == true)
        {
            _lstProducts = _lstProducts.Intersect(lstDeals).ToList();
        }

So every single check convert into two. avoiding this check into single it's fine

Comment: Your example confirms that my recommendation (to move your code into a custom user control) should work just fine in your case.

Comment: yes you are right what you suggested. but if i am using user control, i use this control in two place in a page. so, again i am going to check with two different ID's only right. then how it ll be reduce my back end checking?. I am focusing about back end code optimization only.